# React Redux mapStateToProps parameter for connect function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to return a plain object from a resolved promise in redux connect function?

```
const resolveStateFunction = (state) =>{
    return Promise.resolve(state);
}
const mapStateToProps = async (state)=>{
    const resolvedState = await resolveStateFunction(state);
    return resolvedState;
}
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
    return { apiResponse: apiResponse };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SchoolTemp);
```

the `resolvedState` variable returns a resolved object value but then I am getting an error that says

> that mapStateToProps() in Connect(SchoolTemp) must return a plain
>   object. Instead received [object Promise].

Comment: `async` functions return a promise, so that's why you're getting that error. Usually when dealing with async stuff with Redux there will be some initial/default state. And then async stuff like promises can update state when they are ready with their data, using actions.

Comment: This might help [Async Flow](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-flow)

Answer (score 0):

`mapStateToProps` is expected to return plain object, like `{resolvedState: 'something'}`.

This should help:

```
const mapStateToProps = async (state)=>{
    const resolvedState = await resolveStateFunction(state);
    return {resolvedState};
}
```

Then you can refer `resolvedState` **prop** from your component

Answer (score 0):

`mapStateToProps` Functions Should Be Pure and Synchronous

> Much like a Redux reducer, a mapStateToProps function should always be 100% pure
>   and synchronous. It should simply take state (and ownProps) as
>   arguments, and return the data the component needs as props. It should
>   not be used to trigger asynchronous behavior like AJAX calls for data
>   fetching, and the functions should not be declared as async.

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#mapstatetoprops-functions-should-be-pure-and-synchronous